# Cannot open Visual SVN server

Tags: svn, server

Error SVN server

> Access is denied. (0x80070005)
>   Please check the credentials and server security settings. Learn more about how to configure server security settings to enable remote administration.
>
> Most likely this error is caused by corrupted WMI infrastructure on the server. Learn more about how to repair WMI infrastructure.

[image]

Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your user account must be a member of *VisualSVN Server Admins* local Windows group to get the necessary permissions.

Comment: Account login Windows was  member of VisualSVN Server Admins